# Clicking grid view with drag and drop?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, gridview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Click and drag image to image grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494769/click-and-drag-image-to-image-grid)

I have a few image boxes in my form and I was wondering how can I would place a grid across the form that have a bunch of lines so the whole grid is a bunch of 64 x 64 squares. I need it so I can select an image and place it onto a specific square using the mouse and be able to go through the whole grid and check for example how many of one specific image is on the grid. To give you a better idea of what I'm doing is that I have a few image boxs which contain different 64 x 64 images. There is another image box that shows the image I clicked on last, which is like a brush because whenever you left click a box in the grid it pastes it into that specific box in the grid. I also need it so I can right click the box and delete the image in the box the mouse is over. Finally I need to be able to read all the images in the box and output it into a file that I can later open. I'm using it to create land in a game, which the program will output the needed texture and and where ground level is for the boxs which make up the whole terrain. What I need to know is what kind of thing should I do to be able to do this? I've been trying the past few hours on how I make the boxs and how to know where the mouse is and stuff and I'm completely stuck. A simple idea would be helpful. I actually don't know what control(s) I should use for this so an idea that doesn't involve any grid controls is still very helpful.

Comment: Since your previous question got closed, you just reposted the whole thing ?

Comment: I didn't explain it correctly last time and it looked like I was asking for someone to write code for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best possible idea, but you could use FlowLayoutPanel with WrapContent set to true and FlowDirection = LeftToRight. I dont know about Drag&Drop operation though (never done it with FlowLayoutPanel, buth there are some nice tutorials out there).

You can track your mouse position using mouse events. If you don't want to do that:

You can get absolute position at any time using:

```
Point currentPos = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
```

Then, to get relative position on your (current) control:

```
Point relativeLoc = this.PointToClient(currentPos)
```

... and then, to get control over which your mouse is on FlowLaoutPanel:

```
Control c = flowLayoutPanel1.GetChildAtPoint(relativeLoc);
```